# equivalent norm to uniform norm on $C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I know that on $C[a,b]$ the uniform norm (sup norm) is not equivalent to $L_p$-norm. Can anyone help me find a norm which is actually equivalent to the uniform norm on $C[a,b]$?

Answer (score 1):

Just 'invent' one yourself. Let's say, the norm that is twice the supremum;)

Answer (score 1):

The main difficulty is to avoid writing a norm which is isometric to the sup norm.  You didn't actually state that the norm shouldn't be isometric, but it's a natural nontriviality condition (which is not satisfied by such tricks as scaling the sup norm, or multiplying by some fixed function which is bounded away from zero, as I suggested in an answer I've since deleted).

Here's an approach which produces an equivalent but nonisometric norm: Take the unit ball of the sup norm, add a suitable$^\dagger$ point $f_0$ (and its negative), take convex hull, and consider the result to be the unit ball of a new norm.  The new norm is equivalent to the sup norm with the formal identity map (with isomorphism constant $\le\|f_0\|$), but the unit ball of the sup norm has only two extreme points$^\ast$ (the constants $\pm 1$) while the unit ball of the new norm has at least four (the constants $\pm 1$, and $\pm f_0$).

$^\dagger$ *suitable point $f_0$*: I think it's sufficient to take any function for which there exist $x$ with $|f_0(x)|>1$ (so that $f_0$ will be an extreme point of the new unit ball) and there exist $x$ with $|f_0(x)|<1$ (so that the constants $\pm 1$ remain extreme points as well).  But I haven't checked this very carefully.

$^\ast$ *unit ball of the sup norm has only two extreme points*: Any function with sup norm 1, other than the constants $\pm 1$, can be perturbed up and down in a region away from where it attains its norm, and then written as an average of those perturbations.